# Script displays SQL error: "Table 'leggo.dummy(name, email, password)' doesn't exist", but the table does exist

Tags: sql

I created a database named "leggo", and a table named " dummy" in it with 4 rows: 'Id', 'name', 'email', 'password'. I'm trying to insert some values from a php signup script but it displays SQL error: "Table 'leggo.dummy(name, email, password)' doesn't exist"

Comment: whats is your complete insert query. also what type of database is it e.g (mysql, postgres etc)

Comment: The database is named "leggo" is the schema named "leggo"?  Most databases use `<schema>.<tablename>` not `<database>.<tablename>`